# Blank home page and 404s after switching to HTTPS in ISPConfig 3

Tags: https, ispconfig-3

First encounter with ISPConfig so I am stuck with a very basic problem:
Hosting company activated SSL certificate for a domain and enabled part of the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS: the home page of the website is blank, going to any of the internal pages gives a 404 error (all pages are OK).
In ISPConfig control panel I checked the SSL box, but it stays unchecked; I added to .htaccess the directive I use to redirect to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It does not work.
No Options tab is visible in control panel > Sites where I could add those directives.
Hosting company tech support is lazy/overwhelmed, it takes several days to get a vague answer from them.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are a client of a company that uses ISPConfig?

If so, you can't access the options tab, since it's only available to admin users.

You can enable the HTTP to HTTPS redirect under the web settings -> Redirect

Can you change any other settings? If not, it might be that the admin created your site, and protection is active. This makes it impossible for you to change any settings. The admin should fix that.

The official ISPConfig forums are on https://www.howtoforge.com/community/, I recommend posting there.

Comment: Plain and sad truth is ... domain owner did not purchase SSL certificate.
Thank you very much for your help, should I have other questions about IPSConfig I will post them on that forum.